# Select where number range does not overlap

Tags: oracle, select, range, oracle12c, between

I have two tables that contain records about road construction activites:

- `table_a` is the master list.
- `table_b` is a legacy list.

For each road, in each year, I want to select the records from `table_b` that do not already exist in `table_a`.

Also, the records should **not** overlap spatially along the road. More specifically, the `from_m` and `to_m` of the records in `table_b` should not overlap the `from_m` and `to_m` in `table_a`.

**How can I do this?** I do not have Oracle Spatial.

---

**The data in Excel (for easy viewing):**

Here is what the data looks like in Excel:

[image]

The records in **green** should be selected by the query; the records in **red** should not.

---

**The DDL:**

Table A:

```
  create table table_a 
   (
    id number(4,0), 
    road_id number(4,0), 
    year number(4,0), 
    from_m number(4,0), 
    to_m number(4,0)
   );

insert into table_a (id,road_id,year,from_m,to_m) values (1,1,2000,0,100);
insert into table_a (id,road_id,year,from_m,to_m) values (2,1,2005,0,25);
insert into table_a (id,road_id,year,from_m,to_m) values (3,1,2005,50,75);
insert into table_a (id,road_id,year,from_m,to_m) values (4,1,2005,75,100);
insert into table_a (id,road_id,year,from_m,to_m) values (5,1,2010,10,50);
insert into table_a (id,road_id,year,from_m,to_m) values (6,1,2010,50,90);
insert into table_a (id,road_id,year,from_m,to_m) values (7,1,2015,40,100);
insert into table_a (id,road_id,year,from_m,to_m) values (8,2,2020,0,40);
insert into table_a (id,road_id,year,from_m,to_m) values (9,2,2020,0,40);
insert into table_a (id,road_id,year,from_m,to_m) values (10,3,2025,90,150);
commit;

select * from table_a;

        ID    ROAD_ID       YEAR     FROM_M       TO_M
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1       2000          0        100
         2          1       2005          0         25
         3          1       2005         50         75
         4          1       2005         75        100
         5          1       2010         10         50
         6          1       2010         50         90
         7          1       2015         40        100
         8          2       2020          0         40
         9          2       2020          0         40
        10          3       2025         90        150
```

---

Table B:

```
  create table table_b 
   (
   id number(4,0), 
    road_id number(4,0), 
    year number(4,0), 
    from_m number(4,0), 
    to_m number(4,0)
   );

insert into table_b (id,road_id,year,from_m,to_m) values (1,1,1995,0,100);
insert into table_b (id,road_id,year,from_m,to_m) values (2,1,2001,0,50);
insert into table_b (id,road_id,year,from_m,to_m) values (3,1,2005,20,80);
insert into table_b (id,road_id,year,from_m,to_m) values (4,1,2005,0,100);
insert into table_b (id,road_id,year,from_m,to_m) values (5,1,2010,0,10);
insert into table_b (id,road_id,year,from_m,to_m) values (6,1,2010,90,100);
insert into table_b (id,road_id,year,from_m,to_m) values (7,1,2010,5,85);
insert into table_b (id,road_id,year,from_m,to_m) values (8,1,2015,40,100);
insert into table_b (id,road_id,year,from_m,to_m) values (9,1,2015,0,40);
insert into table_b (id,road_id,year,from_m,to_m) values (10,2,2020,0,41);
insert into table_b (id,road_id,year,from_m,to_m) values (11,3,2025,155,200);
insert into table_b (id,road_id,year,from_m,to_m) values (12,3,2025,199,300);
insert into table_b (id,road_id,year,from_m,to_m) values (13,4,2024,5,355);
commit;

select * from table_b;

        ID    ROAD_ID       YEAR     FROM_M       TO_M
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1       1995          0        100
         2          1       2001          0         50
         3          1       2005         20         80
         4          1       2005          0        100
         5          1       2010          0         10
         6          1       2010         90        100
         7          1       2010          5         85
         8          1       2015         40        100
         9          1       2015          0         40
        10          2       2020          0         41
        11          3       2025        155        200
        12          3       2025        199        300
        13          4       2024          5        355
```

Comment: according to your requirement your reds and greens are  not appropriate please check.

Comment: @nikhilsugandh Can you give me a hint as to which ones are wrong?

Comment: your question is not clear to me although i tried to give solution to you.

Comment: see the answer below but you have already accepted one.I have edited my post with output as you have asked me .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A NOT EXISTS sub-select can help here

```
SELECT *
FROM table_b b
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM table_a a
                WHERE
                    a.road_id = b.road_id AND
                    a.year = b.year AND
                    a.to_m > b.from_m AND
                    a.from_m < b.to_m)
```

Let's look at overlapping ranges (f=from, t=to)

```
a   -------------------f=======================t-----------------

b1a -----f=============t-----------------------------------------
b1b --f=============t--------------------------------------------

b2a -------------------------------------------f======t----------
b2b -----------------------------------------------f======t------

b3  ---------------f=========t-----------------------------------
b4  ------------------------f===========t------------------------
b5  ---------------------------------------f===========t---------
```

The ranges b3, b4 and b5 overlap. for all of them the following is true

```
a.to > b.from && a.from < b.to
```

For b1a, b1b and b2a, b2b that don't overlap this condition is false. For b1a `a.from == b.to`, for b1b `a.from > b.to` therefore the condition `a.from < b.to` is `false`.

For b2a `a.to == b.from`, for b2b `a.to < b.from` therefore the condition `a.to > b.from` is `false`.

The trick is to compare the `from` of one range with the `to` of the other one and vice-versa.

See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/85883/3/0

Comment: your answer is showing the wrong output i checked it .

Comment: See the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/85883/3/0) link I added and compare it with his [image](https://ibb.co/fynWve).

Comment: For what it's worth, I have a related question here: [Select events that represent the most recent work on roads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52081473/select-events-that-represent-the-most-recent-work-on-roads)

Answer (score 1):

[image: see it]this will work :

```
SELECT * FROM table_b b
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM table_a a
                WHERE
                 a.year=b.year and a.from_m<>b.from_m and  a.to_m <>b.to_m );
```

Comment: The OP want non-overlapping sections where as your answer finds records having non-identical sections.